# restriction on the diagonal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi_i:X\times X\to X $ be the projection of the $i$th component and $D_i (i=1,2)$ be
Cartier divisors on $X$. Then is it true that $(\mathcal{O}_X(\pi_1^*D_1)\otimes\mathcal{O}_X( \pi_2^*D_2))|_\Delta=D_1+D_2$ on $X$?
($\Delta=$diagonal)

Comment: The answer is yes, but please define the divisors on $X$ and the pull-back of divisors, and say what is $\times $ for divisors.

Comment: Sorry for being sloppy. I corrected in the statement. Thank you for answering!!